# Rearrange the GeoPandas index after sorting alphabetically

Tags: python, pandas, geopandas

I am working with GeoPandas Dataframe and had to sort alphabetically the Dataframe.

This is the original DataFrame:

|  | SHAPESTArea | SHAPESTLength | geometry | names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1.705685e+06 | 24841.426669 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-43.10567 -22.74888, -43.10568... | Paquetá |
| 1 | 4.056403e+06 | 18303.595717 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-43.17170 -22.77661, -43.17170... | Freguesia (Ilha) |
| 2 | 9.780465e+05 | 7758.781282 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-43.18915 -22.78318, -43.18915... | Bancários |
| 3 | 1.895742e+07 | 21510.059220 | MULTIPOLYGON (((-43.22804 -22.78374, -43.22811... | Galeão |
| 4 | 1.672546e+06 | 8246.109606 | POLYGON ((-43.18039 -22.79940, -43.18022 -22.7... | Tauá |

I want to sort the DataFrame using the `names` column as reference. Due to the special characters (e.g. á, ã), I was unable to use `gdf.sort_values('names', ascending=True)`, as some rows were not being sorted correctly.

Then I came across this function, which resolved my trouble:

`gdf = gdf.iloc[gdf['names'].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]`

My Dataframe now looks like the following:

|  | SHAPESTArea | SHAPESTLength | geometry | names |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 77 | 6.163327e+05 | 4930.770118 | POLYGON ((-43.29425 -22.89034, -43.29536 -22.8... | Abolição |
| 21 | 1.605524e+06 | 6408.772937 | POLYGON ((-43.33724 -22.82594, -43.33705 -22.8... | Acari |
| 125 | 3.149568e+07 | 43744.411247 | POLYGON ((-43.22040 -22.93213, -43.22116 -22.9... | Alto da Boa Vista |
| 20 | 4.345727e+06 | 11471.418826 | POLYGON ((-43.37979 -22.82539, -43.38194 -22.8... | Anchieta |
| 119 | 2.261300e+06 | 9938.098921 | POLYGON ((-43.24866 -22.91959, -43.24879 -22.9... | Andaraí |

But the indexes are now being listed as `77, 21, 125, 20, 119...` instead of `1, 2, 3, 4, 5...`

There is a way to fix the indexes?

Thanks!

Comment: I know in pandas there is a `.reset_index()` method, but I'm not sure if that works in geopandas

Comment: Try adding reset_index() at last. gdf = (gdf.iloc[gdf['names'].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]).reset_index()

Comment: Sadly, if I use ```gdf.reset_index()``` or ```gdf = (gdf.iloc[gdf['names'].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]).reset_index()``` it resets the DataFrame and rearrange as if I used  ```gdf.sort_values('names', ascending=True)```, with special characters not being sorted correctly.

Comment: I've created a new variable to store the DataFrame using the ```reset_index```, and it worked like a charm, but don't know why... The final solution is: ```gdf1 = (gdf.iloc[gdf['names'].str.normalize('NFKD').argsort()]).reset_index()```. Thank you guys!